# PHP Add Currency in Table

Tags: php, rows, currency

I'm trying to add currency together from multiple rows. Below is my code so far. I'm not sure where the SUM should be.

I'd also like to out put the resulting table in a PDF format using FPDF if possible. I tried pasting my code in, but couldn't get it to work, kept giving me the error that it's not in the proper format. I kept hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and entering the code, but it didn't work;

Any advice?

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Accounting Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/table.css"/>
    <script src="../js/table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "rq5f4mkn");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("charitabledb", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounting";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<div id="content">
    <div id="blog">
        <div id="articles" style="width:692px;padding:0;">
            <table width="250" border="1" class="example table-autosort table-autofilter   
         table-autopage:10 table-stripeclass:alternate table-page-number:t1page table-
         page-count:t1pages table-filtered-rowcount:t1filtercount table-
         rowcount:t1allcount" id="t1">
                <thead>
                <tr style="height:35px">
                    <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default table-sortable" title="Click 
          to sort">Date
                    </th>
                    <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default table-sortable"
                        title="Click to sort">Transaction Type
                    </th>
                    <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default table-sortable"
                        title="Click to sort">Account
                    </th>
                    <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default table-sortable"
                        title="Click to sort">Description
                    </th>
                    <th class="table-filterable table-sortable:default table-sortable"
                        title="Click to sort">Amount
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['date']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['transactiontype']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['account']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['description']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['amount']?></td>

                    <?php
                    }
                    mysql_close($con);
                    ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>

                <tr>
                    <td style="cursor:pointer;"
                        class="table- page:previous">&lt; &lt;Previous
                    </td>

                    <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Page <span id="t1page">1</span>&nbsp;of
                        <span id="t1pages">11</span></td>
                    <td style="cursor:pointer;" class="table-page:next">Next &gt; &gt;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><span id="t1filtercount">105</span>&nbsp;of
                        <span id="t1allcount">105</span>&nbsp;rows match filter(s)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Comment: Welcome aboard. Since you're new, I'll offer some pointers rather than downvoting. Start by sharing your code, and explaining what you've already tried :)

Comment: Please read the Markdown primer: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: *Here is my code so far* Welcome to stack overflow. Looks like you forgot to include the code :) Also it is best not to combine disparate questions in one thread. You should open a new question about exporting to pdf.

Comment: @DustinVicent: It is. Here's a pro-tip, first paste your (nicely formatted, please) code, *highlight it all, **and then press CTRL+K***. This way, the code will retain its format, and *still* be highlighted as code.

Comment: Now, what are you trying to do exactly? I can't follow. What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, but I want to add the amount column up. Statements that I'm trying to use are not working, I think it has something to do with the sortable table that I'm using.

Comment: I am not a php person, but can you not just add the amounts to a "total" variable as you loop. Then display the total value after the loop?

Comment: In other words initialize a `total` variable before your loop. Then add the current amount each time you iterate ie `totalAmount += currentAmount`. Then display the final total after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply totalling all values in the table:

```
mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM accounting");
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you, where would I put the statement?

Comment: If you add the * selector to the statement you can replace your existing one.

Comment: It's not working, unfortunately, the table isn't coming up with any amounts that have been added together.

Comment: Are you using $row['SUM(amount)']?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the table that I'm using. It's not putting in the totals for the amounts @ the bottom of the table. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: *If you add the * selector to the statement you can replace your existing one.* If you add `*` to the same statement as `SUM`, you will not get the correct result. You will just get the total for the current `date,transactionType,account and description`, which is essentially the same as  returning the individual `amount` values for each row.